# android - possible to override the default auto-brightness level?

Tags: android, system

I'm wondering if there is any way to override the default brightness level a device uses when it is switched to 'Auto-brightness'?

there's a lot of questions on setting device brightness in general but nothing that I can find on this particular issue.

I know that some ROM's allow this value to modified but I'm hoping it can be done programmatically from a simple app on a non-rooted device.

perhaps it might be possible to 'cheat' somehow? (how - I have no idea ;-p )

anyway - appreciate any help.

cheers.
bvb

Comment: apparently - there are ways to do this, but they seem to bypass the system autobrightness and do it themselves...  
http://www.appbrain.com/app/custom-auto-brightness/com.nnevod.loggraph

Comment: nothing?? no one has any advice on this??